# What does "n-fold axis" mean in symmetry groups?

Tags: rotations, symmetry, solid-geometry, platonic-solids

Reading about the symmetries of a cube, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octahedral_symmetry), they talk about (in the section "Details") "3 x rotation about a four fold axis" etc. I'm not quite sure what "four fold axis" means in the context. Can someone help? Also, since a cube is face transitive, it should be possible to define a group of rotations such that starting with one face, the rotations construct all the other faces. Is there a name for and easy way to identify this group? The full Octahedral symmetries (24) are much more than the faces.

Answer (score 2):

A four fold axis of symmetry is one for which a rotation of $\pi/2$ exists, so that rotation is of order four. The symmetries of the cube are the full octahedral group:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octahedral_symmetry

**Edit**. The edit to the question provides the same wikipedia link. It's all there.

Comment: Sorry, I have a hard time understanding "rotation of $\pi/2$ exists". You can take any axis and rotate about it by any amount you want, no?

Comment: Also, any hint regarding the second part of my question?

Comment: Also, in the link.. what do the numbers 7, 16, 23 mean?

Comment: I am not sure what numbers mean. In that table they range from $0$ to $23$, each occurs just once. Each block contains as many as there are symmetries of that kind, so I suspect they just name the $24$ proper symmetries in some order seemingly not specified here.